# Relation between complexifying ODE and its Laplace transform?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, laplace-transform

Why is complexifying an ODE identical to its Laplace Transform?

Why is $\int_0^\infty f(t) \cdot e^{-st} \, dt  $ the same as complexifying?